# Ubuntu 14.04 slow ethernet connection (40 kbytes/s)

Tags: networking, bumblebee, download-speed

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04, and I have very slow internet.

The download speed is very slow (around 35-45 kbytes/s). This is with wired ethernet.

Windows didn't have this issue.

Comment: I wouldn't say 50°C is hot... mine is running at 53-60 as I type this.

Comment: Now in 56°C. But that's not the main problem!

Comment: @Rasul Kerimov How do you connect to Internet ? Ethernet ? Wifi ? what is the hardware you use ? see https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: @solsTiCe it does say ethernet in the title. @Ras do you mean kbits or kbytes? `

Comment: @Ras, yes sorry!